# Data Selection SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dataset

I have a scenario where I need to select data based on month-end.

Raw data looks like:

| ID | Date | Cost | IS_REVERSED | Reverse_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | $1 | No | NULL |
| 2 | 2021-01-30 | $2 | YES | NULL |
| 3 | 2021-02-01 | $3 | NULL | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-02-03 | $4 | No | NULL |

Please note the `IS_REVERSED` flag column and `Reverse_ID` column. If the transaction is successful in the first attempt the flag is NO, But if the transaction is successful in the second attempt the flag is NULL

My desired output if I run the report for **January** end it should bring all transactions that happened in Jan (even if it reversed is Yes but reversal has not yet happened)

**ID 1, 2**

For next month-end, I need to report data from **Jan and Feb** combined. and the desired output should  be

**ID 1, 3 and 4**

Id 2 should **not** be reported in because that has a reverse flag of Yes

Any pointers to achieve this would be much appreciated.

```
Create table Test_Report
    (ID Int
    ,[Date] date
    ,Cost varchar(100)
    ,Is_reversed varchar(100)
    ,Reversed_ID int)
    
insert into  Test_Report values 
    (1     ,'2021-01-01',       '$1'     ,            'No',            NULL),
    (2     ,'2021-01-30',       '$2'     ,            'YES',            NULL),
    (3     ,'2021-02-01',       '$3'     ,            NULL,            2),
    (4     ,'2021-02-03',       '$4'     ,            'No',            NULL)
```

I need a single query where i can pass [date] as a condition to filter out records. (date < '2021-01-31' should bring id 1,2 )
(date <'2021-02-28' should bring id 1,3,4) ID 2 should not come as the transaction is reversed and we have a new transaction (Id 3) with IS_REVERSE flag as NULL.

Thanks

Comment: @Namish Is that your date column is a varchar column ?

Comment: `01 Jan` This is NOT a date. Is this from last year? this year? 1990?

Answer (score 0):

I used a dynamic SQL query to achieve the results. Since your data is not clear and I see the datatypes are not correct, assumptions are used. So, DML and DDL are included with the answer

```
Create table Test_Report
(ID Int
,[Date] varchar(100)
,Cost varchar(100)
,Is_reversed varchar(100)
,Reversed_ID int)

  insert into  Test_Report values (1     ,'01 Jan',       '$1'     ,            'No',            NULL)
   ,(1     ,'30 Jan',       '$2'     ,            'YES',            NULL)
   ,(1     ,'01 Feb',       '$3'     ,            NULL,            2)
   ,(1     ,'03 Feb',       '$4'     ,            'No',            NULL)


 declare @from  varchar(100) = 'Jan'
  , @to varchar(100) = 'Feb'

 declare @where varchar(max)  
 declare @query varchar(max)

 set @query = 'select * from Test_Report where '

 if @from = @to 
    begin 
       set @where = ' [Date] like ''%'+@from+ '%''   and  ( isnull(Is_reversed,'''') in (''No'', ''YES'', '''')) and  Reversed_ID is null' 
    end 
else
    begin
         set @where = ' ( [Date] like ''%'+@from+ '%'' or [Date] like ''%'+@to+ '%'' ) and    ( isnull(Is_reversed,'''') in (''No'', ''''))' 
    end 

  Declare @Main varchar(max) = @query + @where

  --This statement can be used to test the resulted query
  --select @Main

  exec(@main)
```

[image: Result when from and to dates differ]

Comment: @Namish Let me know if you need any further assistance, Happy to help. If you have any changes let me know. I can help :)

Comment: Thanks @Gudwlk. Appreciate your query but i think this is not exactly what i am after. Let me simplify the query:
`
Create table Test_Report
(ID Int
,[Date] date
,Cost varchar(100)
,Is_reversed varchar(100)
,Reversed_ID int)

  insert into  Test_Report values 
    (1     ,'2021-01-01',       '$1'     ,            'No',            NULL)
   ,(2     ,'2021-01-30',       '$2'     ,            'YES',            NULL)
   ,(3     ,'2021-02-01',       '$3'     ,            NULL,            2)
   ,(4     ,'2021-02-03',       '$4'     ,            'No',            NULL)

`

Comment: I need a single query where i can restrict end date to '2021-01-31' should bring in ID 1,2 and for date '2021-02-28' should bring 1,3,4
Select * from Test_Report where isnull(Is_reversed,'') in ('No', 'YES', '') and [Date] < '2021-02-28'

Comment: I see a  different in data now. Ill check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to impute the date of the report you wish to run. In this case I would declare a variable for your WHERE clause.

[image]

This variable outputs the current date, but you can replace the GETDATE() syntax with a date value to make the query dynamic. Now the WHERE clause...

```
DECLARE @DATEVAR AS DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT *
    ,EOMONTH(#Test_Report.[Date],0) [EOMONTH for WHERE clause]
FROM #Test_Report
WHERE (Is_reversed != 'YES'
        OR Is_reversed IS NULL)
    AND #Test_Report.[Date] <= EOMONTH(@DATEVAR,0)
```

The EOMONTH() function can be used here to evaluate the end of the month selected, and select all records less than that month-end date. Since you want both records where Is_reversed is not YES and is NULL, we need to put an OR clause in parenthesis.

Desired Output:
[image]

A more clever way to deal with the nulls is the ISNULL(,) function. You can use it in your WHERE clause to make that constraint a 1-liner.

```
SELECT *
    ,EOMONTH(#Test_Report.[Date],0) [EOMONTH for WHERE clause]
FROM #Test_Report
WHERE ISNULL(Is_reversed,'No') != 'YES'
    AND #Test_Report.[Date] <= EOMONTH(@DATEVAR,0)
```

Either method should do the trick!